# User settings dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below code

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<h1>Stylish User Settings Menu</h1>

<div id="dropdown" class="ddmenu">
  Landi <img src="../images_app/off.png" width="20" height="20" style="margin-left:100px">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Friend Requests</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#dropdown").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
      if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
        $(this).removeClass("open");
        $(this).children("ul").slideUp("fast");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("open");
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
      }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So,my problem is in `href="#"`  when I fill the `href` for example `example.html` it is not working... So when I remove the script that content `jquery1.8.2` then the `href` tag works but all my project is destroyed.
Any solution how to solve my problem without remove `jQuery`?

Comment: can you please put your code in snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: @SagarKodte there it is https://jsfiddle.net/mmg4amn4/

Comment: Isn't the fiddle working? I changed some of the href's to actual url's and it worked fine.

Comment: how it possible? @n_i_c_k??it's not working for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason is you have `e.preventDefault()` that stops any typical event propagation of that element. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp.

If you still don't want the default behavior, then What you can is, some how get the link that need to be open for the the clicked  element and open it in a new tab or window or what ever you want

You may include the link to the html like

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-link="my-profile.html">My Profile</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then in javascript

```
$("#dropdown").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open($(this).data("link"), '_blank');  
}
```

I have just posted the code without testing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are preventing default action (in this case the href) with `e.preventDefault();`. You need to delete it to make the `<a>` works. Also add `target="_blank"`.

```js
 $("#dropdown").on("click", function(e){
      if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
        $(this).removeClass("open");
        $(this).children("ul").slideUp("fast");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("open");
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">

<div id="dropdown" class="ddmenu">
  Landi <img src="../images_app/off.png" width="20" height="20" style="margin-left:100px">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.es" target="_blank">My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.es" target="_blank">Friend Requests</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.es" target="_blank">Account Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.es" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.es" target="_blank">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/okorvn6y/3/)'s a working example

Comment: Wow!!!yes that is my problem!!!e.preventDefault();!!!pffff WTF im trying 2 hours to find my problem and i forgot to change e.preventDefault();.So thank you very much

Comment: @roliroli consider approving my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `e.preventDefault();`
what it does is that the default action of the event will not be triggered i.e if you click on a an anchor tag it will not take you to a new url.
so change the script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dropdown").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
            $(this).children("ul").slideUp("fast");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("open");
            $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
        }
    });
</script>
```